# Delete duplicate rows and its dependencies in other tables by using Temporary tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, temp-tables

I have a product **table** wish contains a **duplicated rows** and its uniq **Id** is **referenced** in other **6 tables**.

I want to delete these duplicate rows in the product table and inside **the other tables** that depends on my product.

I think about using temporary tables to:

- create global temporary table for each table related to my product
- get duplicate records
- get its dependencies
- save the first rows with min Id
- delete the other rows

I have this idea, but I don't know how to well implement it.

I don't know, if the choice of **temp** tables is right or not.

Thanks for your help and advises.

Comment: Input and expected output ?

Comment: input: product table contains duplicated rows and it's related table contains too duplicated rows => output: delete all duplicate rows @xXx

Comment: Can you share your data model ?an example ?...

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question here. What is it you're asking here?

Comment: Do those 6 referenced tables all have a [foreign key with cascade delete](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php)?

Comment: I'm asking for advises, and if this approach is good to follow @Larnu

Comment: @LukStorms yes all of the 6 referenced tables have foreign key

Comment: And you're not worried that the referenced records in those 6 tables are removed? Or should they point to the remaining product.Id of those dups?  Or have their product_id set to null, or maybe some default dummy product? The point being that to maintain referential integrity, a product.id can't be deleted if it's still referenced. Choices, choices...

Comment: @LukStorms I need to remove these duplicated rows in all tables, because my data now is not coherent for my clients

Comment: You could change the foreign key to a cascading delete (this may require it to be dropped and recreated) then any data you delete in the parent will also be deleted from the child

Comment: (i.m.h.o. I'm kinda against using cascade delete, unless there are solid reasons for it.  Scarry stuff & backup restores could happen...)

Comment: @TesterUser which Sql server version ur usinf?

Comment: @LukStorms so what do you suppose to do?
I thought of temp tables at the beginning, but I don't know it's useful or not!

Comment: @Ljt SSMS V17.1

Comment: SSMS is just a tool to access databases. The version of the Sql Server matters more. But this probably won't require fancy new functionality. Just load the product.id's to delete in 1 temp table, then delete those from the 6 tables before deleting them from the product table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table dbo.hasduplicates
(
    id int identity,
    --assume colA, colB is the entity/unique combo
    colA varchar(10),
    colB int,
    someOtherColumn varchar(40)
);


insert into dbo.hasduplicates(colA, colB, someOtherColumn)
values
('A', 1, 'A1 - 1'),
('A', 1, 'A1 - 2'),
('A', 1, 'A1 - 3'),
--
('A', 2, 'A2 - 1'),
('A', 2, 'A2 - 2'),
--
('B', 1, 'B1 - 1'),
('B', 1, 'B1 - 2'),
('B', 1, 'B1 - 3');


select *
from dbo.hasduplicates;


--temp table holding the to-be-deleted ids (of the duplicates)
create table #ToBedeleted(IdToDelete int);

with dup
as
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by colA, colB /*<--cols of your entity go here*/ order by id) as RowNum
    from dbo.hasduplicates
)
insert into #ToBedeleted(IdToDelete)
select Id
from dup
where RowNum >= 2;

--contains the ids for deletion
select * from #ToBedeleted;

--cleanup the referencing tables
/*
DELETE FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE Table1Id IN (SELECT IdToDelete FROM #ToBedeleted);
DELETE FROM dbo.Table2 WHERE Table2Id IN (SELECT IdToDelete FROM #ToBedeleted);
.............
DELETE FROM dbo.Table6 WHERE Table6Id IN (SELECT IdToDelete FROM #ToBedeleted);
--finally cleanup your products table
DELETE FROM dbo.hasduplicates WHERE Id IN (SELECT IdToDelete FROM #ToBedeleted);
*/

--/*
drop table #ToBedeleted;
drop table dbo.hasduplicates;
--*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that duplicate products have the same `product.name`

If there are more criteria for a dup, then adapt the criteria in the `EXISTS` accordingly.

```
create table #tmpProductsToDelete (product_id int primary key);

-- 
-- collect the products that have a higher id with the same name in the temp table
--
insert into #tmpProductsToDelete
select id
from dbo.Product t1
where exists
(
    select 1
    from dbo.Product t2
    where t2.name = t1.name
      -- and t2.colA = t1.colA
      -- and t2.colB = t1.colB
      and t2.id > t1.id
);
```

Then double check if those are the products to delete.

```
select * 
from dbo.Product
where id in (select product_id from #tmpProductsToDelete);
```

Maybe first copy those dups into a copy of Product. 
Same for the 6 tables with a FK to the Product table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.cpyProduct', 'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 0 *, GetDate() as RemoveOn
  INTO dbo.cpyProduct FROM dbo.Product
  UNION
  SELECT TOP 0 *, NULL FROM dbo.Product;
END;

INSERT INTO dbo.cpyProduct
SELECT *, GetDate() AS RemoveOn
FROM dbo.Product
WHERE id IN (select product_id from #tmpProductsToDelete); 

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.cpyTable1', 'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 0 *, GetDate() as RemoveOn
  INTO dbo.cpyTable1 FROM dbo.Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TOP 0 *, NULL FROM dbo.Table1;
END;

INSERT INTO dbo.cpyTable1
SELECT *, GetDate() AS RemoveOn
FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE product_id IN (select product_id from #tmpProductsToDelete); 

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.cpyTable2', 'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 0 *, GetDate() as RemoveOn
  INTO dbo.cpyTable2 FROM dbo.Table2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TOP 0 *, NULL FROM dbo.Table2;
END;

INSERT INTO dbo.cpyTable2
SELECT *, GetDate() AS RemoveOn
FROM dbo.Table2
WHERE product_id IN (select product_id from #tmpProductsToDelete); 

-- Rinse & repeat for the other 4 tables

SELECT * FROM dbo.cpyProduct;
SELECT * FROM dbo.cpyTable1;
SELECT * FROM dbo.cpyTable2;
```

Then cleanup.

```
--
-- delete them from the 6 tables with a FK to the products table
--

delete from dbo.Table1
where product_id in (select product_id from #tmpProductsToDelete);

delete from dbo.Table2
where product_id in (select product_id from #tmpProductsToDelete);

delete from dbo.Table3
where product_id in (select product_id from #tmpProductsToDelete);

delete from dbo.Table4
where product_id in (select product_id from #tmpProductsToDelete);

delete from dbo.Table5
where product_id in (select product_id from #tmpProductsToDelete);

delete from dbo.Table6
where product_id in (select product_id from #tmpProductsToDelete);

-- remove the dups from the base table
delete from dbo.Product
where id in (select product_id from #tmpProductsToDelete);
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/YLP77221)

Answer (score 0):

One method is store the duplicate id's  in variable and  based on id delete the duplicate records. (Assuming  ProductRefTable is Reference table & ProductId is foreign key)

```
  CREATE TABLE Product
    (
     ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
     Value INT,
     CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY(ID)  
    )


    INSERT INTO Product([Value])
    VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(5),(3),(5)
```

---

```
DECLARE @DupIDS varchar(max)='';   
SELECT @DupIDS =STRING_AGG(ID,',')
FROM Product 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT min(ID) 
                 FROM Product 
                 GROUP BY Value)


Delete From Product 

WHERE id  in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@DupIDS , ','))  


Delete From ProductRefTable

WHERE ProductId  IN (select STRING_SPLIT(@DupIDS ,',')
```